# Issue in creating instance method using prototype in loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have two Models, ModelA & ModelB. Model B contains the following properties:

```
"properties": {
    "firstname": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "middlename": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastname": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
```

I created an Instance method in ModelB like this:

ModelB.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(ModelB) {
  ModelB.prototype.getFullName = function() {
    console.log(this); // Display result output shown below
  }
};

I have the following result in ModelA

someTestVariable:
   { id: 'e0a844e4-6c8a-489a-8bd6-1d62267d311e',
     firstname: 'Thomas',
     middlename: '',
     lastname: 'Henry' 

   }
```

I tried to call the instance method in ModelB from ModelA

```
ModelB.prototype.getFullName();
```

this keyword output the following

```
ModelConstructor {
  firstname: [Getter/Setter],
  middlename: [Getter/Setter],
  lastname: [Getter/Setter],
  id: [Getter/Setter],
  getFullName: [Function],
  save: [Function],
  isNewRecord: [Function],
  getConnector: [Function],
  destroy: [Function],
  delete: [Function],
  remove: [Function],
  setAttribute: [Function: setAttribute],
  updateAttribute: [Function: updateAttribute],
  setAttributes: [Function: setAttributes],
  unsetAttribute: [Function: unsetAttribute],
  replaceAttributes: [Function],
  patchAttributes: [Function],
  updateAttributes: [Function],
  reload: [Function: reload] 
  }
```

I am not sure how to get the firstname, middlename & lastname data in ModelB from ModelA. 
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You cannot call prototype methods directly, you will not have an instance attached to the call. In your call, the `this` will be the prototype object itself which does not have instance data associated with. You seem confused between classes and instances.

Comment: @JuanMendes Can you please tell me how to get firstname in ModelB

Comment: b = new ModelB(...), b.firstName.  as I said above, it seems you need to do some research as to what prototypal inheritance means and then ask a follow up question if needed. But I explained it above, I have a blog post that may prove helpful http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html

Comment: @JuanMendes Sorry didnt get you. Can you please show me the same in code? Can you please update it?

Comment: I showed it above, you have to create an instance with new (or your db engine) and you work with that, you don't call prototype methods directly. Please do some research on what I have suggested

Comment: @JuanMendes  like this? let B = new ModelB.prototype.getFullName(); I need to get the firstname data from ModelA to ModelB getFullName function, inorder to push firstname into another array. How is this possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194291/discussion-between-vishnu-and-juan-mendes).